# Почему такая большая разница по времени выполнения между этими 2-мя способами соединения?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, нужно соединить по частичному совпадению с начала строки.

Соединяемые колонки имеют индексы.

Я могу соединить, как так

```
t.field1 like t2.field1+'%'
```

, могу соединить так(Так как данные позволяют вычислить значение для точного совпадения):

```
t.field1 =LEFT(t2.field1,LEN(t2.field1)-CHARINDEX('/',reverse(t2.field1)))
```

И второй способ во много раз быстрее первого, хотя, по идее они должны идти наравне по времени, так как поиск идет с начала поля.

Почему так?

Comment: Догадка. Вы сами ответили - данные позволяют вычислить значение для точного совпадения. А в первом примере like должна еще поработать

Comment: Я сталкивался с похожими приколами. like и правда иногда медленно отрабатывает

Comment: @vikttur, затраты на вычисления неужели быстрее чем чистый Like?

Comment: Планы выполнения посмотрите и тут приведите. Оптимизаторы современных СУБД очень хитрые. Видя не точное совпадение они вполне могут ожидать, что записей по условию будет слишком много и выбирать совершенно другой путь выполнения (например решить что работа по индексу для такого большого количества не эффективна). А когда точное совпадение они по другому оценивают ожидаемое количество записей.

Answer (score 6):

У этих двух условий разная семантика, и результат запросов с одним и другим условием должен быть разный. Не удивительно, что время выполнения отличается.

Например, для таких данных

```
create table t (field1 varchar(20));
create table t2 (field1 varchar(20));

insert into t values ('A'), ('A/B'), ('A/B/C'), ('A/B/C/D'), ('A/B/C/D/E');
insert into t2 values ('A/B/C');
```

Запрос с первым условием

```
select t2.field1 as t2_field1, t.field1 as t_field1
from t2
    join t t on t.field1 like t2.field1 + '%';
```

даёт результат:

```
t2_field1  t_field1
---------- ----------
A/B/C      A/B/C
A/B/C      A/B/C/D
A/B/C      A/B/C/D/E
```

А запрос со вторым условием

```
select t2.field1 as t2_field1, t.field1 as t_field1
from t2
    join t on
        t.field1 = LEFT(t2.field1, LEN(t2.field1) - CHARINDEX('/', reverse(t2.field1)));
```

даёт другой результат:

```
t2_field1            t_field1
-------------------- --------------------
A/B/C                A/B
```

Т.е. первый запрос для одной строки из `t2` выбирает много строк из `t` (в данном примере - элемент и его "поддерево"), а второй - всего одну ("родителя").